# MediaPlayer can't play song

Tags: java, android

I get list of songs using ContentResolver:

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);
    int count = 0;

    if(cur != null) {
        count = cur.getCount();
        if(count > 0) {
            while(cur.moveToNext()) {
                songs.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
            }
        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

Then I try to play first song from list using MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    player.setDataSource(songs.get(0));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
player.start();
```

And I receive errors:

> 12-09 16:08:12.662 135-554/? D/FFMPEG: android source close
>
> 12-09 16:08:12.662 135-554/? D/FFmpegExtractor: SniffFFMPEG failed to
>   sniff this source
>
> 12-09 16:08:12.666 1324-1324/? E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 2
>
> 12-09 16:08:12.666 1324-1324/? E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)

Comment: See docs media player "state" . before play u need to call init()

Comment: It's works. Thank you.